# Jquery Event binding on newly cloned rows

Tags: jquery, delegates, clone

I have been working on a functionality where, i need to implement auto save on each cell of a table and also, add a new row if that cell is the last cell of the last row. The newly cloned row should also have the same binded blur events. I am able to add the new row but the event are not getting triggered. Here is the code..
Please help stuck for long now..

```
$("#myTable1").live("blur", function(){
         var elementValue = document.getElementById("<%=count%>").value.toString();
         var value = $("#<%=count%>_hidden").attr('value').toString();
         var qualValue = "<%=qualValue %>";
    var sequenceNumber = "<%=sequenceNumber %>";
    var parentAttrbtInstId = "<%=parentAttrbtInstId %>";
    var parentId = "<%=parentId %>";
    var attrbtId = "<%=attrbtId %>";
    var attrbtInstId =  $("#<%=count%>_hidden").attr('attrbtInstId').toString();
    var rootId = "<%=rootId %>";
    var itemId = "<%=item.getItemId()%>";
    var currentCount = "<%=count%>";
    var cellCount = "<%=cellLimit%>";
    var rowId = "row_<%=rowCounter%>";
    var rowCount = <%=rowCounter%>;



      if(elementValue.toLowerCase() != value.toLowerCase()){
         $.ajax({
           url: "<portlet:resourceURL id='autoSaveAction' />",
             type: 'POST',
             dataType: 'json',
             data: { elementValue:elementValue,qualValue:qualValue,sequenceNumber:sequenceNumber,parentAttrbtInstId:parentAttrbtInstId,parentId:parentId,attrbtId:attrbtId,
              attrbtInstId:attrbtInstId,rootId:rootId,itemId:itemId},
             success : function(response) {
                 if (response.status == "SUCCESS") {
                    jsonstr=JSON.stringify(response.result);
 var temp=JSON.parse(jsonstr);
 $("#<%=count%>_hidden").attr('attrbtInstId',temp.attrInstId);
 document.getElementById("<%=count%>_hidden").value = temp.attrValue;
 if(currentCount == cellCount){
 cloneRow = $("#myTable1 tr:last").clone(true);

     cloneRow.attr({
       'id': function(_, id) { 
 return "row_"+(rowCount+1);
       }            
     }).end().appendTo("#myTable1");

 cloneRow.find("input").each(function() {
     $(this).attr({
       'id': function(_, id) { 
 if (id.indexOf("hidden")!= -1){
 return currentCount + "_hidden";
 }else{
        return ++currentCount;
 }
       }             
     });
   }).end().appendTo("#myTable1");
 cloneRow.find("select").each(function() {
     $(this).attr({
       'id': function(_, id) {
       if (id.indexOf("hidden")!= -1){
 return currentCount + "_hidden";
 }else{
        return ++currentCount;
 }
 }              
     });
   }).end().appendTo("#myTable1");
 cloneRow.find("textarea").each(function() {
     $(this).attr({
       'id': function(_, id) {
        if (id.indexOf("hidden")!= -1){
 return currentCount + "_hidden";
 }else{
        return ++currentCount;
 } 
       }              
     });
   }).end().appendTo("#myTable1");
 }

 } else {
      }
      },
     error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){ 

     }
         });
          }
     });
         });
```

Comment: The live() function is deprecated. You should use on() or delegate()

Comment: You are adding your blur event to the table. Do you want that event to fire when you leave your table context? If you want the input to have its own blur function, you'll need to bind to the input, not the table.

Comment: Thanks for the response.I have multiple input and select elements in the table. How do I make a generic call for blur on every element in the table, such that It should propagate through the cloned elements ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want all of the elements in the table to have the listener you first need to give them all a class, (like "table-elem"), and attach a listener like this:

```
   $("#myTable1").on("blur", ".table-elem", function() {

        //your function you want to run
   });
```